Finetuned quantized model is hallucinating. How to reduce hallucination from quantized finetuned model?
Problem:
I have fine-tuned an open source LLM model (Falcon-7b-sharded) using PEFT finetuning technique. But the output of the model is not satisfactory. The model seems to hallucinate. How can the output be improved. I have limited resources. My training environment contains the following GPU and CUDA:
Training GPU
CUDA: 12.1
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P5000
Model Output

Fine tuning Code
from datasets import load_dataset

# Specify the name of the dataset
dataset_name = "timdettmers/openassistant-guanaco"

# Load the dataset from the specified name and select the "train" split
dataset = load_dataset(dataset_name, split="train", download_mode="force_redownload")
# Importing the required libraries
import torch

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig

# Defining the name of the Falcon model
model_name = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16"

# Configuring the BitsAndBytes quantization
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
load_in_4bit=True,
bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
)

# Loading the Falcon model with quantization configuration
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
model_name,
quantization_config=bnb_config,
trust_remote_code=True
)

# Disabling cache usage in the model configuration
model.config.use_cache = False
# Load the tokenizer for the Falcon 7B model with remote code trust
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)

# Set the padding token to be the same as the end-of-sequence token
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
# Import the necessary module for LoRA configuration
from peft import LoraConfig

# Define the parameters for LoRA configuration
lora_alpha = 16
lora_dropout = 0.1
lora_r = 64

# Create the LoRA configuration object
peft_config = LoraConfig(
lora_alpha=lora_alpha,
lora_dropout=lora_dropout,
r=lora_r,
bias="none",
task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
target_modules=[
"query_key_value",
"dense",
"dense_h_to_4h",
"dense_4h_to_h",
]
)
from transformers import TrainingArguments
# Define the directory to save training results
output_dir = "./results"

# Set the batch size per device during training
per_device_train_batch_size = 2

# Number of steps to accumulate gradients before updating the model
gradient_accumulation_steps = 4

# Choose the optimizer type (e.g., "paged_adamw_32bit")
optim = "paged_adamw_32bit"

# Interval to save model checkpoints (every 10 steps)
save_steps = 10

# Interval to log training metrics (every 10 steps)
logging_steps = 10

# Learning rate for optimization
learning_rate = 2e-4

# Maximum gradient norm for gradient clipping
max_grad_norm = 0.3

# Maximum number of training steps
max_steps = 50

# Warmup ratio for learning rate scheduling
warmup_ratio = 0.03

# Type of learning rate scheduler (e.g., "constant")
lr_scheduler_type = "constant"

# Create a TrainingArguments object to configure the training process
training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
output_dir=output_dir,
per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
optim=optim,
save_steps=save_steps,
logging_steps=logging_steps,
learning_rate=learning_rate,
fp16=True,  # Use mixed precision training (16-bit)
max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
max_steps=max_steps,
warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
group_by_length=True,
lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
)
from transformers import TrainingArguments
# Define the directory to save training results
output_dir = "./results"

# Set the batch size per device during training
per_device_train_batch_size = 2

# Number of steps to accumulate gradients before updating the model
gradient_accumulation_steps = 4

# Choose the optimizer type (e.g., "paged_adamw_32bit")
optim = "paged_adamw_32bit"

# Interval to save model checkpoints (every 10 steps)
save_steps = 10

# Interval to log training metrics (every 10 steps)
logging_steps = 10

# Learning rate for optimization
learning_rate = 2e-4

# Maximum gradient norm for gradient clipping
max_grad_norm = 0.3

# Maximum number of training steps
max_steps = 50

# Warmup ratio for learning rate scheduling
warmup_ratio = 0.03

# Type of learning rate scheduler (e.g., "constant")
lr_scheduler_type = "constant"

# Create a TrainingArguments object to configure the training process
training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
output_dir=output_dir,
per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
optim=optim,
save_steps=save_steps,
logging_steps=logging_steps,
learning_rate=learning_rate,
fp16=True,  # Use mixed precision training (16-bit)
max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
max_steps=max_steps,
warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
group_by_length=True,
lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
)
# Iterate through the named modules of the trainer's model
for name, module in trainer.model.named_modules():
    # Check if the name contains "norm"
    if "norm" in name:
        # Convert the module to use torch.float32 data type
        module = module.to(torch.float32)

trainer.train()

Code for using the fine tuned model
# Importing the required libraries
import torch

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig

# Defining the name of the Falcon model
model_name = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16"

# Configuring the BitsAndBytes quantization
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
load_in_4bit=True,
bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
)

# Loading the Falcon model with quantization configuration
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
model_name,
quantization_config=bnb_config,
trust_remote_code=True
)

# Disabling cache usage in the model configuration
model.config.use_cache = False

# Load the tokenizer for the Falcon 7B model with remote code trust
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)

# Set the padding token to be the same as the end-of-sequence token
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

# Loading PEFT model
PEFT_MODEL = "omarfarooq908/falcon-7b-finetuned01"
# PEFT_MODEL = <Username>/YOUR_MODEL_URL_REPO. 

config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(PEFT_MODEL)
peft_base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    config.base_model_name_or_path,
    return_dict=True,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map="auto",
    trust_remote_code=True,
)

peft_model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(peft_base_model, PEFT_MODEL)

peft_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(config.base_model_name_or_path)
peft_tokenizer.pad_token = peft_tokenizer.eos_token

from transformers import GenerationConfig

def generate_answer(query):
  system_prompt = """Answer the following question truthfully.
  You are a chatbot that can coherently hold conversations with humans, in English"""

  user_prompt = f""": {query}
  : """

  final_prompt = system_prompt + "\n" + user_prompt

  device = "cuda:0"
  dashline = "-".join("" for i in range(50))

  encoding = tokenizer(final_prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
  outputs = model.generate(input_ids=encoding.input_ids, generation_config=GenerationConfig(max_new_tokens=256, pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id, \
                                                                                                                     eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id, attention_mask = encoding.attention_mask, \
                                                                                                                     temperature=0.4, top_p=0.6, repetition_penalty=1.3, num_return_sequences=1,))
  text_output = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

  #print(dashline)
  #print(f'ORIGINAL MODEL RESPONSE:\n{text_output}')
  #print(dashline)

  peft_encoding = peft_tokenizer(final_prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
  peft_outputs = peft_model.generate(input_ids=peft_encoding.input_ids, generation_config=GenerationConfig(max_new_tokens=256, pad_token_id = peft_tokenizer.eos_token_id, \
                                                                                                                     eos_token_id = peft_tokenizer.eos_token_id, attention_mask = peft_encoding.attention_mask, \
                                                                                                                     temperature=0.4, top_p=0.6, repetition_penalty=1.3, num_return_sequences=1,))
  peft_text_output = peft_tokenizer.decode(peft_outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

  print(f'PEFT MODEL RESPONSE:\n{peft_text_output}')
  print(dashline)


generate_answer("What is normal body temperature?")


Hi, usually you fine-tune model on specific task. And by that I mean something very specific, for example answering questions in a specific domain (for example in medicine). In this situation you have a particular measurable metric that can show if the performance on your dataset improved or not.  
In your question you are using your own judgment on the answer from the fine-tuned model. Thus it is not clear why you think that model didn't learn anything: you were finetuning on the dataset that doesn't have jokes, but want a model to perform better on generating jokes.

Also the dataset that you are using for the finetuning most probably was already used during pretraining. And thus finetuning on this dataset unlikely to improve the model answers. Also you were finetuning for 50 steps - this is quite a lot for such small dataset, this caused the model to forget the knowledge that it knew during pretraining.

Should I decrease the steps? I want to finetune the base model to act like a general chatbot. Basically I want the model to be a general chatbot that can respond to simple questions. Like for example, "what is a normal body temperature?", "How are you doing?", "When did French Revolution take place?". Thank you for taking out time to reply @JohnnyCheesecutter

I would consider looking for git projects that doing smth similar to your task. For example to this one: https://github.com/bofenghuang/vigogne/blob/main/examples/train/falcon/train_sft_chat_qlora.sh
They stopped training after three epochs.
Also when doing inference check that you added roles to the prompt - I don't see any roles added inside your implementation of generate_answer. For example if you are fine-tuning on openassistant-guanaco dataset than your prompt during inference should look like this...

"### Human: {query} ### Assistant:" In this case model will understand that you are in chat mode and will start generating answer for the assistant.
